# How to handle Derived Classes with overridden Generic Types in Lists?

Tags: c#, class, design-patterns, derived

I want to create a resource manager with customly typed derived resource classes like Texture1D, Texture2D, etc. Therefore I would like to override a generic type from the parent, so I`m able to return the resource data without casting it from object. (Also structs are possible with this solution).

See this approach if the text above was a little bit unclear:

I create an interface `IResource`. (1)
Then an abstract class implementing this interface. (2)
And finally my custom resource, which derives from `Resource<T>`. (3)

```
//1
public interface IResource : IDisposable

//2
// This class returns Data as T
public abstract class Resource<T> : IResource 

//3
// This class returns Data as GLEXTexture2D
public class Texture2DResource : Resource<GLEXTexture2D>
```

Basically, I have a ResourceManager with a List of `IResource`'s which can add resources like this:

```
Texture2DResource resource = new Texture2DResource("a path", ResouceThreadAccess.LOCAL);
resourceManager.RegisterResource(resource);
```

Is this an acceptable design decision? In my oppinion the generic overriding code looks a bit confusing when creating new resources. Is there a better way to solve this tripple inheritance?

Comment: So far, I don't see a problem at all (in having specific subclasses of a generic class, that deal only with one specific type). How do you plan on getting the actual `GLEXTexture2D` when (presumably) you only have `resourceManager` at hand?

Comment: There is nothing *overridden* here. `Resource<T>` **implements**  `IResource` which requires to implement `IDisposable` as well. `Texture2DResource` **derives** from `Resource<GLEXTexture2D>`. Good design. Implementing or deriving from a non-generic type is a good way of making different generic types compatible.

Comment: @Corak I actually dont need a "get" function in my resource manager. It sits on the same looping thread an keeps track of the RAM/VRAM size, disposing operations and statistics. But thanks for mentioning that, I may need this function some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use the above pattern (ie: interface, with abstract base class, and the actual class itself). To answer if it is acceptable design decision, it depends on what you want to achieve (although generally it is a good design)...

With `resourceManager`, you could loop through them and call the method in the interface (in which you can override as different implementation in the child object). This way, you don't even need to worry about casting from 'object'.

However, if you have a lot of child-specific classes, which mean that from `resourceManager` you need to identify the specific child class -- then the 'generic' nature and abstract base class may not help as much.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some days a week I just sit in the office and researching such structures. It seemed a good and dynamic solution but I didnt know how far this can go. Also it looks kind of wrong because of all these inheritations. Maybe it have to look like this, in a language without anonymous generic Lists :)